# RadImageEditor onSaving Event do not allow to send respose script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am using Telerik RadImageEditor control with version 2013.1.220.40, the Control is put on the page and the page is displayed in a RadWindow. All I want is to pass a url or do not pass(for Update and Add Scenario respectively) and after croping the image in the popup when user clicked on the save button in the Image Editor, I want to send the path back to the page by adding response script to the Ajax Manager. All the things is working fine, but the response script is not working. I tried to put a hidden field to save value in onSaving event and then capture the onClientSaved event of Image Editor, but the value of hidden field alwasy return empty. it seems that all the values reset after leaving the onSaving event. while the image is saved successfully in the directory.
      I don't know what is the thing  am missing which cause this error. please help me!

here is the server side code.

```
public void RadImageEditor1_ImageSaving(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.ImageEditorSavingEventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = e.FileName;

            //If Derectory not exist, creat new
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TempImagePath"])))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TempImagePath"]));

            //Set Image Path
            Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TempImagePath"] + "/" + filename.Trim() + Extention;
            if (File.Exists(Path))
                File.Delete(Path);

            //Save  image to temp directory
            e.Image.Image.Save(Server.MapPath(Path));

           //Send image path back to the page where this popup Appeared
            RadAjaxManager1.ResponseScripts.Add("CloseAndSendPath('" + Path +"')");
            //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "CloseAndRebind", "<script>CloseAndRebind('" + Path + "');</script>");

            //Cancel built in Saving.
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

        public string Path
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["Path"] == null)
                    return string.Empty;
                else
                    return ViewState["Path"].ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["Path"] = value;
            }
        }

        public string Extention
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["Extention"] == null)
                    return string.Empty;
                else
                    return ViewState["Extention"].ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["Extention"] = value;
            }
        }

        public void BtnDeleteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Context.Cache.Remove(Session.SessionID + "UploadedFile");
            Path = string.Empty;
            Extention = string.Empty;
            imgUploaded.ImageUrl = string.Empty;
        }

        public void BtnCropClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panelCrop.Visible = panelUpload.Visible;
            panelUpload.Visible = !panelCrop.Visible;
        }

        public void BtnUploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            imgUploaded.ImageUrl = Path;
        }

        public void RadAsyncUpload1_FileUploaded(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.FileUploadedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Clear changes and remove uploaded image from Cache
            RadImageEditor1.ResetChanges();
            Context.Cache.Remove(Session.SessionID + "UploadedFile");
            using (Stream stream = e.File.InputStream)
            {
                byte[] imgData = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                ms.Write(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);

                Context.Cache.Insert(Session.SessionID + "UploadedFile", ms, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), TimeSpan.Zero);
            }

            //Save to Temp Folder as well
            string fileExt = e.File.GetExtension().ToLower();
            if (fileExt != ".jpg" && fileExt != ".png" && fileExt != ".jpeg" && fileExt != ".bmp" && fileExt != ".gif")
            {
                lblError.Text = "Please upload photo only in .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .bmp or .gif format";
                return;
            }
            string filename = e.File.FileName;
            Extention = fileExt;
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TempImagePath"])))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TempImagePath"]));
            Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TempImagePath"] + "/" + filename.Trim();
            e.File.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path));
        }

        public void RadImageEditor1_ImageLoading(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.ImageEditorLoadingEventArgs e)
        {
            //Handle Uploaded images
            if (!Object.Equals(Context.Cache.Get(Session.SessionID + "UploadedFile"), null))
            {
                using (EditableImage image = new EditableImage((MemoryStream)Context.Cache.Get(Session.SessionID + "UploadedFile")))
                {
                    e.Image = image.Clone();
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["usertype"]))
                {
                    string usertype = Request.QueryString["usertype"];
                    switch (usertype)
                    {
                        case "employee":
                        case "customer":
                            RadImageEditor1.ExternalDialogsPath = "~/Controls/Crop/Employee/ImageEditorDialogs";
                            break;
                        case "company":
                            RadImageEditor1.ExternalDialogsPath = "~/Controls/Crop/Company/ImageEditorDialogs";
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Context.Cache.Remove(Session.SessionID + "UploadedFile");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["path"]))
                {
                    Path = Request.QueryString["path"];
                    imgUploaded.ImageUrl = Path;
                    System.IO.FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path);
                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        Extention = file.Extension;
                        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(Path), FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            byte[] imgData = new byte[stream.Length];
                            stream.Read(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);
                            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                            ms.Write(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);

                            Context.Cache.Insert(Session.SessionID + "UploadedFile", ms, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), TimeSpan.Zero);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and here is the markup with java script

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js">
            </asp:ScriptReference>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js">
            </asp:ScriptReference>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js">
            </asp:ScriptReference>
        </Scripts>
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="loadingPanel1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="loadingPanel1">
        <AjaxSettings>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
    <asp:Panel ID="panelUpload" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnUpload">
        <telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="RadAsyncUpload1" runat="server" OnFileUploaded="RadAsyncUpload1_FileUploaded"
            MaxFileSize="5242880" OnClientValidationFailed="validationFailed" AllowedFileExtensions="jpg,png,gif,bmp"
            AutoAddFileInputs="false" OnClientFileUploadRemoved="fileRemoved" MaxFileInputsCount="1"
            HideFileInput="true" Localization-Select="Browse">
        </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
        <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ViewStateMode="Disabled"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelButtons" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload Image" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                OnClick="BtnUploadClick"></asp:Button>
            <asp:Button ID="btnCrop" runat="server" Text="Crop" OnClick="BtnCropClick" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="BtnDeleteClick" />
            <asp:Image ID="imgUploaded" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="150px" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="panelCrop" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <telerik:RadImageEditor ID="RadImageEditor1" runat="server" Width="750px" Height="480px"
            ToolsFile="~/Utilities/Tools/ImageUploadToolsFile.xml" OnImageLoading="RadImageEditor1_ImageLoading"
            OnImageSaving="RadImageEditor1_ImageSaving" OnClientLoad="ImageEditorLoad">
            <Tools>
                <telerik:ImageEditorToolGroup>
                    <telerik:ImageEditorTool Text="SaveImage" CommandName="SaveImage" ImageUrl="~/images/toolBarSprite.png" />
                </telerik:ImageEditorToolGroup>
            </Tools>
        </telerik:RadImageEditor>
    </asp:Panel>
    <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function validationFailed(sender, eventArgs) {
                $telerik.$("#asyncUpload").html("Validation failed for '" + eventArgs.get_fileName() + "'.").fadeIn("slow");
            }
            function fileRemoved(sender, eventArgs) {
                $telerik.$("#asyncUpload").html('').fadeOut("slow");
            }


            function waitForCommand(imageEditor, commandName, callback) {
                var timer = setInterval(function () {
                    var widget = imageEditor.get_currentToolWidget();
                    if (widget && widget.get_name() == commandName) {
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        callback(widget);
                    }
                }, 100);
            }
            Telerik.Web.UI.ImageEditor.CommandList["SaveImage"] = function (imageEditor, commandName, args) {
                var dt = new Date();
                var year = dt.getFullYear();
                var month = dt.getMonth();
                var day = dt.getDate(); var hour = dt.getHours();
                var min = dt.getMinutes();
                var newdate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + "-" + min;

                imageEditor.saveImageOnServer(newdate, true); //saves the image on the server - it either overwrites the file or keeps both files
            };

            function ImageEditorLoad(imgEditor, args) {
                //open the Crop tool dialog with a little timeout
                setTimeout(function () {
                    imgEditor.fire("Crop");
                }, 0);
            }

            function CloseAndSendPath(arg) {
                GetRadWindow().BrowserWindow.UpdateImageUrl(arg);//a method from page where this popup appeared
                GetRadWindow().close();

            }

            function GetRadWindow() {
                var oWindow = null;
                if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow; //Will work in Moz in all cases, including clasic dialog
                else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow; //IE (and Moz as well)
                return oWindow;
            }
        </script>
    </telerik:RadScriptBlock>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server events of the RadImageEditor are callbacks, so you cannot register scripts in them. This is how the MS AJAX frameworks operates with callbacks. Take a look here to see what exactly is a callback and how it differs from the partial postback you expect: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-03-21/different-ways-to-make-a-request-to-the-server.